# Angular 2 - Adding a class when the div is reaching on browser top

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<div class="main-menu-wrapper home-menu **class to be added here**" >
      <div class="main-menu-inner">
          <a href="#" class="home-logo">
              <i class="logo"></i>
```

i need to add a class when the div reaches the top of the browser,

**Requirement** is to start animation when each div hits on the top.
(it's a single page website,with anchoring)

how this can be done in angular 2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular has a function decorator by the name of `HostListener` that accepts an event name as an argument. When that event gets fired on the host element it calls the associated function. we can use it to detect when an element reach the top of the browser.

```
  @ViewChild('componentDiv') componentDiv: ElementRef;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    const element = this.componentDiv.nativeElement;
    const viewportOffset = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const top = viewportOffset.top;
    if (top <= 0) {
        // Do something
    }
  }
```

the HTML template could be something like this

```
<div style="border: solid 1px black" #componentDiv>
  <p>
    Angular is here.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you soo much for your replay
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined - getting an error like this 

import { Component, OnInit, Inject, HostListener,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class MyappComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('componentDiv') componentDiv: ElementRef;

@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    const element = this.componentDiv.nativeElement;
    const viewportOffset = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const top = viewportOffset.top;

    if (top === 0) {console.log('working') }
}

Comment: @Aashiqcr,  Did you put `#componentDiv' in div element?

Comment: ,thank you, the error got cleared ( i have removed that id for a while, my mistake)

Comment: hi 
could you help,
i need to add an class when that particular div touches top 
**HTML**
[ngClass]= "{'wraperchange': isTop}"
......
isTop = false;
...
const top = viewportOffset.top;
    if (top === 0) {
      this.isTop = true;
    } else {
      this.isTop = false;
    }

Done Like this , but no change

Comment: Well, change `if (top === 0)` to `if (top <= 0)` and see if anything changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class you wish to use at the beginning and the class of the elements you wish to animate. Then call the get() method to start listening. It will create a list of all elements with the given class and on scroll will check if they are near the top, if so it will add the class you specified and remove the element from the list. When the list is empty it will remove the listeners. This is one time animation.

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

  constructor(
    private ngzone: NgZone
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // call the listener when you are ready
    this.animateElements.get();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // don't forget to clear your listeners
    this.ngzone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.floatingHeader.scroll, true);
    });
  }

  public animateElements = {
    classToAdd: 'active', // will add this class
    classToListenFor: 'myClass', // listen for these elements
    elements: <any>[],
    get: ():void => {
      // run outside angular to prevent change detection on every scroll
      this.ngzone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.animateElements.scroll, true);
      });
      let elements:any = document.getElementsByClassName(this.animateElements.classToListenFor);
      // let angular a moment to build and select the html
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (elements) {
          resolve();
        }
      }).then(() => {
        Object.keys(elements).forEach((key:any) => {
          let obj = {
            offset: elements[key].offsetTop,
            element: elements[key]
          }
          this.animateElements.elements.push(obj);
          this.animateElements.check(obj);
        });
      });
    },
    check: (e):void => {
      if ((window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) >= e.offset) {
        e.element.classList.add(this.animateElements.classToAdd);
        this.animateElements.elements.splice(this.animateElements.elements.findIndex(row => {
          return row == e;
        }), 1);
      }
    },
    scroll: ():void => {
      if (this.animateElements.elements.length <= 0) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.animateElements.scroll, true);
        return;
      }
      this.animateElements.elements.forEach(e => {
        this.animateElements.check(e);
      });
    }
  }
```